# Automapper Profile - fields and multi threading

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

TLDR: Does Automapper instantiate a profile before each use?

I'm using Automapper Profiles and dependency injection.

One mapping looks like this:

```
public class MyQuestionableProfile : Profile
{
    private CalcResult value;

    CreateMap<X, Y>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.s1,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => calculation(src).Field1))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.s2,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => calculation(src).Field2));
```

(there's a lot more going on, but the question pertains to the above)

`calculation(src)` is quite an expensive operation, so I would like to perform this only once per mapping. My initial thought was to add

```
.BeforeMap((src, _) => value = calculation(src))
```

as part of the mapping, then use `value` during mapping to `s1` and `s2`.

I suspect this won't work. If each profile is instantiated only once, then multiple threads will thrash the contents of `value`.

Any insights/alternative solutions appreciated.

Comment: Did you try just running your app and seeing what it does? Or perf testing it?

Comment: Your question seems to be more about when the delegate in MapFrom is called? Is that correct?

Comment: `BeforeMap` would work. You can share state safely somewhere in your destination object or in the AM provided `context.Items`. Profiles are singleton configuration objects, unrelated to your task.

Comment: It "works" in the sense that so far, it returns what I expect. But I don't see a way to provoke a race condition.

Comment: But I think the better solution would be to use `IncludeMembers(s=>Calculation(s))`. That should only be evaluated once.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all commenters. After some consideration and digging into Lucian Bargaoanu's advice on using `.BeforeMap`, I ended up using `.AfterMap` with a local variable, like so:

```
.AfterMap((src, dest) =>
        {
            var value = calculation(src);
            dest.s1 = value.Field1;
            dest.s2 = value.Field2;
        });
```

Comment: While this works, it doesn't integrate with the AM configuration validation. `IncludeMembers` does because you'd still have resolvers for the destination fields.